# How will meta-discussion be decided?

Tags: discussion

There are some questions here on meta, that are asked to find a proper policy. How are they decided.

Some examples:

- [Identify This Movie Questions?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/66): Should I vote to close them or encourage them?
- [Subjectivity and Film Study : How to deal with it?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/66): Same here, are we closing such questions?
- [Questions about reviews and reviewers](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/65/66)
- [Should we cover TV Series here?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/66)
- [What's trivia and where do we draw the line?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/66)

So, is there a way to form from this questions a policy? Or should I decide myself after reading the different points (and made one myself)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that a successful stack-exchange site becomes (largely) self regulating as people gain privileges including the ability to close questions.

It is the responsibility of the people that have these privileges to conform to the policy that is worked out through the meta-discussion, which of course may change with time as the site grows, and problems arise.

There is the safety net of the stack-exchange assigned moderators.

The only thing I am not aware of are how to change the FAQ.

Comment: If you start fixing this http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-should-our-faq-contain I think a moderator will come along and edit the faq for us. Or when a pro-tem is appointed he/she will edit the faq.